# Using Alerts in SwiftUI Frameworks

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am developing a SwiftUI UI framework that will be used in other projects where I cannot access the source code.

The framework needs to show an alert. To do this, I use the `.alert()` view modifier inside the framework.

This works fine, as long as the app that consumes the framework (where I don't control the source code) does not also add a `.alert()` to a parent view of the framework. If the app does this, the alert inside the framework stops working.

This is obviously not ideal, because the user that consumes my framework should not have to worry about internal implementation details, and should be free to use an alert if they want.

I have added some example code here that demonstrates my problem. This can be run in a Playground if you want to run it yourself. Note the comments showing which parts work and which parts don't work.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ParentView()
    }
}

// This code would be in the app, controlled by the consumer
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showAlert = true
            }) {
                Text("App button")
            }
            FrameworkView()
            
        }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            // This alert works perfectly fine
            Alert(title: Text("This is inside the app"))
        }
        
    }
}

// This code would be provided by the framework, controlled by me
struct FrameworkView: View {
    @State var showAlert: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showAlert = true
        }) {
            Text("Framework Button")
        }.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
            // This alert is never shown
            Alert(title: Text("This is inside the framework"))
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Under normal circumstances, the solution would be to place the alert in `ParentView` on `Button` instead of `VStack`, but because I cannot control what the consumer of my framework writes, this will not work in my case.

Any suggestions on how I could:

a) Avoid this problem, or
b) Warn the user if they set an alert that conflicts with the framework's internal alert?

Comment: This is a SwiftUI bug (worth submitting feedback to Apple). The possible solution is via framework API design - giving result of error/alert back to framework client and let them decide how to show/handle that case.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for the suggestions, I also posted this to the Apple Developer Forums (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655653). It will be interesting to see if anyone from Apple sees it there. For now, I added a workaround using UIKit as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to display the alert within the library, so that the user is free to use the SwiftUI alert in their code.

I used this code:

```
struct AlertRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var shouldShow: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomAlertController {
        return CustomAlertController()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomAlertController, context: Context) {
        if shouldShow {
            uiViewController.showAlert()
        }
    }
}

class CustomAlertController: UIViewController {
    var isShowing = false
    
    func showAlert() {
        // Prevent displaying multiple times
        guard !isShowing else { return }
        isShowing = true
        
        let alert =  UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
            self.isShowing = false
        }
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else {
                return
            }
            
            window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply add `AlertRepresentable` somewhere in your view hierarchy.